# Media query not running for small sizes

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Inside my panel I want to set all the text to center align when the page sizes to < 768, but my media query is not working to center the text. Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fht0wtwp/)

```css
@@media all and (min-width : 768px) {
            .text-left {
                text-align: center;
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 well">
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">My Profile</a></p>
        <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">Interests</a></p>
        <p>
          <span class="label label-default">News</span>
          <span class="label label-primary">W3Schools</span>
          <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
          <span class="label label-info">Football</span>
          <span class="label label-warning">Gaming</span>
          <span class="label label-danger">Friends</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
        <p><strong>Ey!</strong></p>
        People are looking at your profile. Find out who.
      </div>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p contenteditable="true">Status: Feeling Blue</p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>John</p>
           <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Bo</p>
           <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Jane</p>
           <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
           <p>Anja</p>
           <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="55" width="55" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 well">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <p>Upcoming Events:</p>
        <img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
        <p><strong>Paris</strong></p>
        <p>Fri. 27 November 2015</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Info</button>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE! - I set the media query to

```
@@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
        .text-left {
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
```

and when I open Chrome it works fine. But if I open IE 11 when a default window size of something around 900px the text is centered (not good). FYI - if I do a slight window resize the text re aligns back to the left! Is this a weird IE bug??

Comment: can you check  `@@media`, because it will be `@media`.

Comment: You need to solved your spelling mistake `@@media` to `@media`

after check this problem.

Comment: check this link it's working well IE 11 [copen_link](http://codepen.io/ashikjs/full/bBNEvx/)

Comment: Please check this link:-https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 3):

Have you set a viewport meta tag?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It this tag is not set, media queries will not work predictably.

Comment: Solved my problem:)

Answer (score 2):

For Small Device You can't use `min-width`.

Best way you can specifice all **Min** and **Max**.

```
@media all and (max-width: ***px) and (min-width: ***px){ }
```

**More Example:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* Tablets and Desktop */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    /* Phones */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* Portrait Phones */
}
```

Are you worried about **all** and **only screen** ?

Please make a scene about this Article Link:
[link_1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)   [Link_2](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Difference-between-media-ONLY-screen-and-media-screen-queries)

Also You can read some few Stackoverflow Q about this:

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries)

**Update Answer for Problem of IE -11**

Same Question on Stackoverflow 
   [Link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083493/internet-explorer-11-using-media-query-css)
   [Link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059414/media-queries-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11)

**Solution:**

```
@media all and (max-width: ***px) {
     //Media Query CSS
    }
```

**Live_link:**  [link_1](http://codepen.io/ashikjs/pen/bBNEvx) [link_2](http://codepen.io/ashikjs/pen/bBNEvx)

Comment: ok so I use @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and it works fine in Chrome, but when I open it in IE 11 the text is centered even when the screen is bigger then 767px. Why is IE acting funky but Chrome is ok?

Comment: If I do a slight resize of the screen, the text shifts back to left-align! Is this a weird IE bug?

Comment: give me moment for make more information about your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
@media all and (max-width : 768px) {
            .text-left {
                text-align: center;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not `@@media`, instead it's `@media`.

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .text-left {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using ASP.Net MVC and it is @@media, not @media

Comment: Glad you mentioned that in your question and downvoted my answer. Take a look at your own fiddle, using  `@media`. It's working as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/fht0wtwp/1/

Comment: I guess my concern is more about IE vs Chrome, even though I didn't mention it in the original post. It works fine in Chrome, but if I open IE and start the page at something like 850px the text is centered (not good), and if I do a very slight resize the window re sets the text appropriately (left align). Whhy is thios only in IE and not Chrome?